# Someone please explain to me what does this javascript going to replace with /<\S[^>]*>>/g

Tags: javascript

This Javascript
`.replace(/<\S[^>]*>>/g, " ");`
I didnt know what does it replace, can someone explain to me?

Comment: You can see by using a regexp explainer, for example: http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: The regex in the title and the body of the question aren't the same, which one are you asking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the regex is `/\S[^>]*>>/g` looks like replace an entire line up to and including `>>`, allows for single '>'.

Can be ...

```
This line>>
```

... or ...

```
This Too
>>
```

Otherwise, it will start with a `<` (single or more) and end with `>>`